# Show Previous and Next Date Value in Mysql in One Row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this, i'm using MySQL and still stuck to show date in previous record.

```
intDateId |  dateLeave  | dateCreated | intUpdateOrder
1         |  2018-04-01 | 2018-04-01  |  NULL
2         |  2018-04-02 | 2018-04-01  |  NULL
3         |  2018-04-11 | 2018-04-02  |  1
4         |  2018-04-20 | 2018-04-02  |  2
```

This is my query so far, i'm still unable to show previous date:

```
    SELECT 
     intDateId, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(dateLeave) AS datePrevious, // i'm stuck here
     GROUP_CONCAT(dateLeave) AS dateCurrentUpdate, 
     intUpdateOrder
    FROM leave_date
    WHERE intUpdateOrder IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY intUpdateOrder
```

What i want is like this:

```
dateCreated | datePrevious             | dateCurrentUpdate   | intUpdateOrder
2018-04-02  | (2018-04-01, 2018-4-02)  | (2018-04-11)        | 1 // datePrevious WHERE intUpdateOrder NULL
2018-04-02  | (2018-04-11)             | (2018-04-20)        | 2 // datePrevious WHERE intUpdateOrder 1
```

Thank you

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: i'm using version 5

Comment: What are the (foreign key) relationships between rows? This table looks as if it was a log table or something.

Comment: So what you are saying is that for the record, in the previous records append all the `date leave` for the same `intUpdateOrder` value?

Comment: @Raunak Thomas yes

Comment: No need Foreign key, it is just show previous record GROUP BY intUpdateOrder. Show current date and previous row date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query

```
SELECT
  q1.dateCreated,
  q2.datePrevious,
  q1.dateCurrentUpdate,
  q1.intUpdateOrder
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t.*, 
      @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS rank
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          IFNULL(intUpdateOrder,0) intUpdateOrder,
          MAX(dateLeave) dateCurrentUpdate,
          MAX(dateCreated) dateCreated
        FROM leave_date
        GROUP BY intUpdateOrder
      ) t,
      (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) r
    ORDER BY intUpdateOrder
  ) q1
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      t.*, 
      @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rank
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          IFNULL(intUpdateOrder,0) intUpdateOrder,
          GROUP_CONCAT(dateLeave) datePrevious
        FROM leave_date
        GROUP BY intUpdateOrder
      ) t,
      (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
    ORDER BY intUpdateOrder
  ) q2
ON q1.rank=q2.rank+1
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/006e88/17